# What kind of regression to use in predictive model for a positive-only value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, predictive-models, excel

I'm trying to use regression in Excel to predict the % of bin contamination (dependant variable), based on my independent variables that are generally relating to demographics such as age/household size/CALD etc.

I have attempted to use linear regression with multiple combinations of independent variables, but the end result is that there are always some predictions that are negative numbers. The dependent variable, contamination, cannot be a negative number in reality.

I believe I should be using a different kind of regression, but I'm not exactly a statistician so I'm not sure what kind would be appropriate. I've looked into logistic and profit regression but I don't think they're the type of regression I need.

Is there a kind of regression (or other test) that may be more suitable for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What was the problem with logistic regression?

Comment: Thsi seems to a typical use case for beta regression: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0061623 It is unlikely, though, that this can be done with Excel...